# GA4 traffic source data in bigquery incorrect

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I had linked up my google analytics 4 for a week, export daily to bigquery

but when i checked the result in bigquery, the traffic source simply doesn't add up.
for example, in bigquery it doesn't appear any 'facebook', as it appeared in google analytics report

which part did i missed out during setup the bigquery linking?
does anyone have the same issue?

**traffic source in google analytics**

[image]

**traffic source in bigquery**

[image]

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

GA4 BQ export uses same schema as firebase BigQuery export. You can find the schema documentation here https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en

The field you're looking at is not traffic source of the session, but 'Name of the network that first acquired the user.'

What I've found so far is that traffic attribution in GA4 is still not very good. I hope Google is trying to improve it. There's also no way to exclude self-referral traffic as you can in UA.

Comment: It's 2021 and traffic attribution is still broken in GA4 Google Big Query Export.

Comment: How can we get traffic source of the session in this case ? Is it the same for GA ?